# how to get max and min value of a column from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get Min and Max value of Column using one query. Is that Possible?

Here is my code:

```
$this->db->select_max('fare');
$this->db->select_min('fare');
$this->db->from('travels_detail');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: replace both select with this single line, ```$this->db->select('MIN(fare) as minfare, MAX(fare) as maxfare');```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$this->db->select('MAX(fare) as max_fare, MIN(fare) as min_fare');
$this->db->from('travels_detail');
$query = $this->db->get();
```